# is there a way to grant permissions in redshift so that other users of the group can run dbt models?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbt

We have a group of users that have access to our data warehouse dev environment and I am trying to grant this group access to modify and/or locally run the dbt models I have made.

I tried using a post-hook to grant all users of the schema access to the schema but users of the groups are still getting a permission denied message whenever they tried to execute a dbt run command from their terminal on any of my models in this schema.

```
  post-hook:
    - "grant usage on schema {{ this.schema }} to group data_team"
    - "grant select on {{ this }} to group data_team"
```

Ideally, all users in the data_team group should be able to (locally) overwrite models created by other users that they have have fetched from the git repo storing our dbt models files.

Comment: Have you tried with the newer functionality? https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/grants#configuring-grants

Comment: I had not seen it @MichałZawadzki. Thanks. I will try it at work tomorrow.